# LINQ with Entity Framework - basic question

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to learn linq to sql/objects as quick as possible. I have a database with a Category table, and a sub_category table. A Category can have many Sub Categories. As a lesson, I am getting a list of categories. User enters the primary key from a displayed category, and then I wnt to display all sub categories.

Displaying the categories was easy... But Entity Framework has removed the foreign keys from Sub Category! I expect to see a category Id in the sub category table (As there is in the SQL server database model).

Instead, I have some CategoryReference property... How do I manage this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BudgieMoneyEntities db = new BudgieMoneyEntities();

    var categories = (
        from category in db.categories
        select category).ToList();

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Categories:");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    foreach (category cat in categories)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00} {1}", cat.category_id,
            cat.description));
    }

    int categoryId = WaitForKey();

    var subcategories = (
        from subcategory in db.sub_category
        where subcategory ?? ? 
        select subcategory).ToList();
}
```

The ?? is where I have got stuck... How do I do this where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var subcategories = (
    from subcategory in db.sub_category
    where subcategory.category.category_id == categoryId
    select subcategory).ToList();
```

The names of the properties `category` and `category_id` can be different. You can look at your model in the EF designer what the actual names are. If the `category` property is missing, make sure you've got a foreign key relationship between the categories table and the subcategories table.

You also want to change the default names of entities and properies in the EF designer. For instance, use plural names for sub collections. For instance, use `db.SubCategories` instead of `db.sub_category`. That makes it much more readable.

Comment: Thanks Steven! That worked. Fantastic. I'm trying to pluralise the names. Do I have to manually modify the entities? If so, if I need to later refresh the model from the database, I'll need to manually rename them again?

Comment: You need to manually modity the entities and their relationships. Changes to the database are still a bit work (as it has always been in software development). Prevent removing entities to readd them after you made database changes. That will be a lot of work, since you have to rename everything again. That's the price to pay when you want to keep your code as clean as possible ;-)

Comment: Thanks Steven - Foreign keys all established nicely, so it's just the names I have to change in my linq entities. Thanks for the assistance.